# Getting an EOFError, two instructors unable to find why

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a question for a CMPT 103 class, I am using python 3.7 and Wing IDE 101 6.1. We run the code through a local university program that tests for all the parameters.

**The Test and Error:**

Test: `get_input(iterable)`

Setup

```
iterable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Input (stdin)

```
p
@
2.0

a
-1
7.3
17
4
3
```

Crash

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "L1_WD.py", line 62, in get_input  
    step = input("Enter 'A' (for ascending) or 'D' (for descending): ").upper()  
  File "/dev/fd/63", line 31, in Icf0aea90  
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

**The Code:**

```
def get_choice():
   x = input("Select option (1 to 5): ")
    while True:                   #Keep prompting user till they get it correct
        if len(x) != 0 and x.isdigit():
            x = int(x)
            if 1 <= x <= 5:
                return x                              #User got it correct
        x = input("Invalid option. Please enter a number between 1 and 5: ")

iterable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]    
def get_input(iterable):
    n = len(iterable)
    i1 = get_int ("Enter an index: ", n)
    i2 = get_int ("Enter another index: ", n)

    step = input("Enter 'A' (for ascending) or 'D' (for descending): ").upper()
    while len(step) == 0 or step not in ["A", "D"]:
        step = input("Enter 'A' (for ascending) or 'D' (for descending): ").upper()
    if step == 'A': 
        step = 1                  
    else: 
        step = -1
    return (i1, i2, step)

def get_int(prompt, n):
    x = input(prompt)
    while True:                    #Keep prompting user till they get it correct
        if len(x) != 0 and x.isdigit():
            x = int(x)
            if 0 <= x <= n-1:
                return x                              #User got it correct
        x = input(f"Invalid option. Please enter a number between 1 and {n-1}: ")
```

Comment: The code snippet works alright for me. What are the input values that you are entering for prompts ```index``` and ```another index```?

Comment: when I test each function it runs fine for me as well but crashes when the instructors "tests" through the program. My inputs are 1-5 for get_choice, 0-10 and a or d for get_input. Along with all the tests outside the parameters

Comment: Main thing i find on the internet is similar to this article "An EOFError is raised when a built-in function like input() or raw_input() do not read any data before encountering the end of their input stream. The file methods like read() return an empty string at the end of the file." from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-catch-EOFError-Exception-in-Python

Comment: It's not very clear what kind of the 'tests' you mentioned are failing. Are you trying to read the inputs from a file?

Comment: The only visible report generated is what I posted under Test and Error. This is what a correct test showed  Test: def get_choice()     Input (stdin)
a
? 
3.4
0
6
2
Output (stdout)
Problem
Your program
Select option (1 to 5): a
Invalid option. Please enter a number between 1 and 5: ?
Invalid option. Please enter a number between 1 and 5: 
Invalid option. Please enter a number between 1 and 5: 3.4
Invalid option. Please enter a number between 1 and 5: 0
Invalid option. Please enter a number between 1 and 5: 6
Invalid option. Please enter a number between 1 and 5: 2

Comment: It looks like there's an automated script that tests your program? From what I observe from your previous command it seems that the testing program does not look for the inputs that you are asking for/ anticipating, it anticipates fewer inputs. It looks like it only requires a single input (without any input message) and attempts to get the output from that solely. You might need to revisit the problem and the input/output pattern it expects. Since the input provides fewer inouts, but your program requires more, it comes to the end of the *test input* file and gives the EOF error.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. I've only skimmed the code but it seems to do a lot of unrelated things like input validation. As well, `get_choice` is unused. Plus `/dev/fd/63` indicates that the code is being run through a Unix anonymous pipe, but it's not obvious how. Is that from your IDE or from the local university program? What is the local university program?